# Comparing of data

Tags: c#, serial-port, timestamp

How can i notify the program that i received common data?
Given that i had a string of data declared as RxString.
Data received are in the format of

```
T   61     26.7
```

Is there a way to tell the system that there are data of the same number(the number as T) being received thrice? As I will need the program to execute something else if that happened...

eg. Data received

```
T   161     26.7
T   161     22.7
T   161     26.7
T   22      20.6
```

Program "sensed" about receiving common number data thrice. As a result, execute the following code.

But there are problem such as:

1. the data appears as the whole string above.
2. the number could be of one/two/three digits.

Should i make use of this event handler?

```
mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the answer in temp string and then check the part of number if exist in the mySerialPort.DataReceived and is exist do whatever you want

Comment: "put the ans in temp string" meaning i should actually try to split my string then pick out the part which i need to compare?

Comment: @Athena Yes you can keep a temp string with last string and one other witch is the complete string